# Delete attribute from json metadata in postgres (9.4.7)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a table xyz that has a jsob column called metadata, which looks something like

```
"{"decisions": {"final_decision": "ADVANCE"}, "exception": {} }".
```

I want to remove the 'exception' attribute and have an sql

```
update xyz set metadata = metadata - metadata->'exception' where process_id='1e3aeac3';
```

But this gives me an exception while running 
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb - jsonb 
LINE 1: update xyz set metadata= metadata - 'exception'...

HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

I tried searching but I wasn't able to get around the cast issue.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument of the delete (-) operator is `text.`

If you want to delete the attribute, use it's key:

```
update xyz 
set metadata = metadata - 'exception'
returning *;

                   metadata                   
----------------------------------------------
 {"decisions": {"final_decision": "ADVANCE"}}
(1 row)
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/55d9e/4)

The operator was introduced in Postgres 9.5

In Postgres 9.4 use the function:

```
create function jsonb_remove_key(json_object jsonb, key_to_remove text)
returns jsonb language sql immutable as $$
    select jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
    from jsonb_each(json_object)
    where key <> key_to_remove
$$;

update xyz
set metadata = jsonb_remove_key(metadata, 'exception')
returning *;
```

Comment: I get the below error when i use the sql:                                                    ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb - unknown
LINE 1: update trackable_status set metadata= metadata -'exception' ...
                                                       ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: I think you need to do things differently in postgres. When i create the same sample table xyz and run the query u provided in pgadmin, it gives the same above error.

Comment: Upgrade Postgres. You should mention your server version in the question, especially is it is not the latest one.

Comment: It is 9.4.7. I have updated my post with the version. Is there any workaround for this version